# new Object { } Construct

Tags: java, object

In Java, the standard way to create an object is using

```
MyClass name = new MyClass();
```

I also often see the construct

```
new MyClass() { /*stuff goes in here*/ };
```

I've been looking online for a while and can't find a good explanation of what the second construct style does or how it does it.

Can someone please explain how and why you would use the second construct?

Comment: Just one thing: consider using `Object` as a placeholder for the dummy classname, because `Class` is the name of a class itself! It is rather uncommon to extend the class `Class`, especially anonymously!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This construct makes actually two things: 1) It declares an anonymous class which extends the class you use in the constructor and 2) creates an instance of this anonymous class.

Edit: When using such a construct you can observe the anonymous class by looking at the generated `.class` files. There is the normal `MyClass.class` file and another one for each anonymous subclass: `MyClass$1.class` for the first and so on.

Comment: So would a good use case be for objects that you're going to use? For example, objects you would immediately put into an array?

Comment: My Main use case would be for an implementation of a simple interface (just one method) or to customize an adapter (e.g. java.awt.event. stuff). Another use case is provided by @Nathan-Hughes. Simple Rule: Only do the simplest stuff in an anonymous class and use subclasses / own classes for the rest

Comment: Technically speaking, it *declares* a new class rather than creating one.  ("Creating" has the implication that something happens at runtime ... which is not the case for the class itself.)

Comment: Can I add a new constructor to the derived class using this construct?

Comment: @DanC: Yes and No. You can't add a constructor, but you can add a simple code block with `{ /* your code */ }` in there, which gets executed on object creation.

Comment: Here's a good one:  `logger.log(Level.INFO, "look {0} no {1}", new Object[] {"ma", "hands"})`.  You can use any Objects in the array.

Answer (score 14):

You would use the second construct in the case that you want to make an anonymous class. if you have a method that takes a callback as an argument, you might want to specify the implementation of the callback inline as opposed to giving it a name and putting it in a separate file or declaring it elsewhere in the same file.

There's also a trick called [double brace initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization) where you can get around not having syntax for literal maps and lists by using anonymous classes, like this:

```
Map map = new HashMap() {{put("foo", 1); put("bar", 2);}};
```

Here the nested braces create an instance initializer. The object bound to map is not a HashMap, its class is an anonymous class extending HashMap. (That means if you have a PMD rule about classes needing to declare serial uids then it will complain about this.)

Double-brace initialization is a fun trick to know but don't use it in real code. It's not safe to pass around the map created like this, because the inner object keeps a reference to the outer instance so if anything in the program holds onto a reference to the map it keeps the outer object from getting garbage-collected. There are also problems with serialization.

Answer (score 8):

As others have already said, it creates an instance of an anonymous class, subclassing `Class`. Here's an example how it is commonly used:

```
panel.addMouseListener(
  new MouseAdapter () {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
  }
);
```

The above code creates an instance of an anonymous class which extends MouseAdapter. In the anonymous class the method `mouseEntered` has been overridden to demonstrate that the anonymous class works basically as any other class. This is very convenient and common way to create (usually simple) listeners.

Comment: How to build the MouseAdapter class in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Second construction creates an instance of anonymous class which is a subclass of `Class`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to new a object by a protect constructor from another package, you can use:

```
new Foo() {};
```

otherwise you will get an access error. It equals anonymous subclass inherited from Foo class.

Answer (score 0):

From jdk8 onwards you may have seen different syntax seems like creating an objects while using lambda expressions.

**NOTE:** Lambda expressions don't get translated into anonymous inner classes, they use [invoke dynamic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html) that was introduced in Java 7 to execute functional methods.

**For Example:**

```java
public class LambdaSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //If implementation is only one statement then {} braces are optional
        Runnable oneLineImplRunnable = ()->System.out.println("This is one line lambda expression");
        //Multiple statements in the implementation then {} braces are mandatory
        Comparator<StudentTest> stdComparator = (StudentTest s1,StudentTest s2)->{
            if(s1.getFirstName().equals(s2.getFirstName())) {
                return s1.getLastName().compareTo(s2.getLastName());
            }else {
                return s1.getFirstName().compareTo(s2.getFirstName());
            }
        };
    }
}
```